# 'BeautifulSoup' has no attribute '__version__'

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, ipython

while using jupyter notebook using the code

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
print ("BeautifulSoup version:%6.6s" %BeautifulSoup.__version__)
```

I got this error

> AttributeError: type object 'BeautifulSoup' has no attribute '**version**'

I installed bs4 using python setup.py install. It showed in the installation " c:\users...\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\beautifulsoup4-4.4.1-py3.5.egg "

Answer (score 9):

For `BeautifulSoup` version 4, you should've done this way instead :

```
>>> import bs4
>>> print ("BeautifulSoup version:%6.6s" % bs4.__version__)
BeautifulSoup version: 4.4.1
```